# Data View is not populated in wicket7

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-7

I have implemented below code for repeating view

```
DataView documents = new DataView("documents", dataProvider, new Long(20)) {
   @Override
   protected void populateItem(Item item) {
   //do some code
};
```

When I debug the code, debug point is not going inside of populateItem method, while dataprovider is having list of document and implement Idataprovider interface, so due to this there is no data is populated.

We have moved application from wicket 1.3 to 1.7 after that we are facing this problem.

I don't know why it behaves like this.

Comment: One reason could be that the DataView itself or its parent is invisible.

Comment: Could you please tell me flow after calling dataview constructor to populateItem(Item item).

Comment: @martin-g How is depends on visibility of dataview itself or parent. If I am not wrong after calling constructor its will call populateoverride method.

Comment: @martin-g I have update my question with more info. we have migrated wicket from 1.3 to 1.7

Comment: `populateItem()` is called at render time. This could be much later than the construction time. Once you add the dataView to a parent container (e.g. a WebPage) Wicket will call `dataView.onInitialize()`. Later when the complete component tree is fully constructed Wicket will call Page#render() and this will call #render() for all children recursively. At that time dataView.populateItem() will be called. But it will be called only if dataView.isVisible() returns true. There is no reason to populate it if it won't be rendered.

Comment: @martin-g Yes you are correct but why debug point is not going inside of populateItem() while i have set visible is true. can you please help me.

Comment: Maybe the dataprovider does not return any data? Put a breakpoint on it's `size()` method?

Comment: @martin-g RobAu  : Yes, i have tried debug again and see when DataView API is calling DataProvider have data and set this data after that somehow dataprovider dont have any data and showing me that "Internal error occurred, see error log for more detail", but i didn't see any error in logs.

Comment: In that case your logging configuration must be broken. It seems you have a runtime error in your IDataProvider impl and because of this DataView#populateItem() is not called.

Comment: @martin-g FYI we have migrated wicket from 1.3 to 1.7 after that we are getting this problem. how to solve  logging configuration issue.

Comment: @RobAu could please provide any solution for this.

Comment: its look like problem with `dataprovider` does not have any data . Thats the reason it doesn't come to populate.

Comment: Thanks all of you for your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got solution after so many debug. problem is wicket migration.

earlier we are using wicket 1.3 and in this one `IDataProvider` having `Iterator<? extends T> iterator(int first, int count);` and now wicket 1.7 changed with `Iterator<? extends T> iterator(long first, long count);` so we override this method with `return null;` value that's why we are getting null in data Provider.